# Can I import a module that has in it the python file where I wrote the import statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

```
TopFolder -
          -FirstFolder
          -SecondFolder
          -main.py
```

Inside main.py:

```
from TopFolder import *
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'TopFolder'
```

Comment: What are you trying to import? Are you trying to import modules from FirstFolder and SecondFolder? Because `from TopFolder import *` looks like you are trying to import main into main.

Comment: Please ensure you have TopFolder file in your project

Comment: Probably, this question has been asked and solved, check this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder

Comment: The image you are linking to does not look like the problem you posted...

Comment: Thanks so much Gino, you were right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is to import `FirstFolder` and `SecondFolder` modules into main.

Now, trying to do `from TopFolder import *` will result in a circular import, because main will be importing itself (main.py is part of *), which will do the `import *` again, ... and so on. Furthermore, doing `import *` is discouraged (see [Why is “import *” bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad)
).

A better solution is to define FirstFolder and SecondFolder as [packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).
Then import specific modules from those packages in main.

```
TopFolder
 |- FirstFolder
    |- __init__.py
    |- foo1.py
 |- SecondFolder
    |- __init__.py
    |- foo2.py
 |- main.py
```

In foo1.py:

```
def bar1():
    return "bar 1"
```

In foo2.py:

```
def bar2():
    return "bar 2"
```

In main.py:

```
# from TopFolder import *  # Don't do this
from FirstFolder import foo1
from SecondFolder import foo2

print(foo1.bar1())
print(foo2.bar2())
```

Result:

```
$ python3 main.py
bar 1
bar 2
```

Comment: Gino Mempin, Thank you so much. I got it now. main.py at the level of packages. imports in main.py calling package imports. Just as your example.